# Not able to update row data in ag-grid angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am not able to update row data using rowNode.setDataValue('key','value').

```
    gridApi: GridApi;
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    frameworkComponents: {
        buttonRenderer: GridActionsComponent,
        customTooltip: CustomTooltip
    },
    onGridSizeChanged: (event: GridSizeChangedEvent) => {
        this.onGridSizeChanged(event);
    },
    onGridReady: (event: GridReadyEvent) => {
        this.gridApi = event.api;
    },
};

updateRowData(data) {
    const rowNode = this.gridApi.getRowNode('0');
    rowNode.setDataValue('status', 'active'); // here is throwing error as undefined
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr with this error? with the code snippet above, there is no way to know what's really happening.

Comment: your parameter in getRowNode should be a number by default if you are not defining getRowNodeId yourself. I see you are passing 0 as  a string

Comment: throwing Error: "status" is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `id` property on your `rowData` or have you defined `getRowNodeID` function?

[From docs:](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#rowNodes)

> `getRowNode(id)`  Returns the row node with the given ID. The row node ID is the one you provide with the callback `getRowNodeId(data)`, otherwise the `ID` is a number auto generated by the grid when the row data is set.

I suppose you are getting `undefined` cuz this `function`

```
const rowNode = this.gridApi.getRowNode('0');
```

returns `undefined` : (means nothing, means you don't have that id).

`('0')` should work if you not defined `getRowNodeID` function, cuz by default ag-grid use `rowIndex` as `ID`.

Comment: I didn't define getRowNodeID () , using default rowIndex and getting data into rowNode. Getting error while updating the row data by rowNode.setDataValue('status', 'active')

Comment: @SreenivasuluKuruva show full code and I will try to help

Comment: After debugging more and more found that it throwing Error: "status" is read-only. it is causing the issue.